# Install latest android support library CLI

Tags: android-sdk-manager

I am trying to use ContextCompat class from the Android Support Library.  I am using only CLI tools to build an app.  So I figured I have to get a jar.  I entered the following:

```sh
$ sdkmanager --list | grep extras
Warning: File /root/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
  extras;android;m2repository | 47.0.0      | Android Support Repository     | extras/android/m2repository/
  extras;android;gapid;1                                                                   | 1.0.3        | GPU Debugging tools
  extras;android;gapid;3                                                                   | 3.1.0        | GPU Debugging tools
  extras;android;m2repository                                                              | 47.0.0       | Android Support Repository

$ sdkmanager "extras;android;m2repository"

$ ls /opt/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/26.0.0-alpha1/*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1767 Sep 12 16:16 /opt/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/26.0.0-alpha1/support-v4-26.0.0-alpha1.aar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   32 Sep 12 16:16 /opt/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/26.0.0-alpha1/support-v4-26.0.0-alpha1.aar.md5
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   40 Sep 12 16:16 /opt/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/26.0.0-alpha1/support-v4-26.0.0-alpha1.aar.sha1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1572 Sep 12 16:16 /opt/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/26.0.0-alpha1/support-v4-26.0.0-alpha1.pom
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   32 Sep 12 16:16 /opt/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/26.0.0-alpha1/support-v4-26.0.0-alpha1.pom.md5
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   40 Sep 12 16:16 /opt/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/26.0.0-alpha1/support-v4-26.0.0-alpha1.pom.sha1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  261 Sep 12 16:16 /opt/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/26.0.0-alpha1/support-v4-26.0.0-alpha1-sources.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   32 Sep 12 16:16 /opt/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/26.0.0-alpha1/support-v4-26.0.0-alpha1-sources.jar.md5
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   40 Sep 12 16:16 /opt/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/26.0.0-alpha1/support-v4-26.0.0-alpha1-sources.jar.sha1
```

The problem is, I cannot see any jar files of the latest Android Support Library.  What should I do to download it?

Answer (score 0):

The folder */opt/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/24.1.1* in my case contained about 2MB *aar* file, which contained classes.jar file, which I finally and ended up using.  It is unclear what is the purpose of other low-size files in the other folders like 26.0.0.